# AS3: Simulating RotationX with Matrix

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, rotation

I have to use Flash CS3, so I can't use the properties rotationX, roationY and rotationZ.

I have a movieclip, that looks like this. It is now flat, no 3D rotation or shearing

[image]

But what I want is that this movieclip has a rotationX, or that it is a bit in perspective like this:

[image]

As I said, I can't use rotationX, so I have been playing around with Matrix.
But I can not get it right.

Here is how I try to do it

> myMC.transform.matrix = new
>   Matrix(1,0.15,0.35, 1, 0, 0);

And this is the result

[image]

Can you help me to get the matrix right, or is there another way?

Thank you,
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your life easier and just download a 3D engine for flash 9:

http://away3d.com/downloads

Either that or you can modify your CS3 installation to produce SWF files that target flash 10+

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that overkill? Using a whole 3D engine just to add some perspective?

Comment: lol yeah it is overkill. But you've gotta weigh out for yourself what is more overkill. Spending time and researching trying to figure out a proper method to fake 3D transformation in a level of the VM that absolutely does not support any such thing, or just taking an existing 3d engine and using it to get the same job done. Note that there is away3D LITE which is a very stripped down version of the engine with just basic 3D transformation and some model loading support.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, rotationX and rotationY are not affine transforms (they obviously do not preserve parallelism between lines), so they cannot be represented by matrix multiplication in 2D space. It is, however, affine in 3D space (where the non-preservation of parallel lines is an apparent effect of the 2D projection, not of the rotation)

Comment: Thanks, any other solution to archive this?

Answer (score 0):

i believe what you are trying to do is to get a correct affine transformation matrix.

[image]

FYR (Transformation Matrix) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

***Edits***

For more information about 3D transforms and their matrices, 
Here, see if this applies.

http://www.cosc.brocku.ca/Offerings/3P98/course/lectures/2d_3d_xforms/

***Edits 2***

A blog post about 3D transform in CS3 and CS4.

> 3d Rotation the easy way: Buy Flash
>   CS4 uggh! I’m still using CS3 and only
>   for my Flash software. My illustrator,
>   photoshop, premiere, and aftereffects
>   are still at the lowly level of CS2
>   and for economic reasons, I’m stuck w/
>   my outdated software configuration for
>   awhile.  But if you’re not in my boat
>   or on the same sea as my boat,
>   consider buying the latest, greatest
>   CS4 Flash to make 3D manipulation
>   inherent in flash display objects. 
>   Yep, inherent, built in, easy.
>
> In Flash CS3 and below, a display
>   object (i.e. sprite or movieclip) only
>   recognizes one rotation property
>   (rotation: Indicates the rotation of
>   the DisplayObject instance, in
>   degrees, from its original
>   orientation, which is usually the
>   upper left, corner or 0,0). This
>   property only rotates objects in the
>   2D flat space of the Flash stage.  To
>   make 3D work in this flash, one must
>   “fake” it with math. Lots of math,
>   Points, lines, fills, trig, arrays,
>   and sometimes Matrices.  Yippee kayae!
>
> In Flash CS4 and above (as of writing
>   there is no above), a display object
>   (i.e. sprite or movieclip) recognizes
>   four (4) rotation properties. Holy
>   Cow! Yeah, four rotation properties:
>
> rotation: Same as in CS3. 2D rotation.
>   rotationX: spin that shit around the X
>   axis of the stage, i.e. vertical
>   flipping. rotationY: spin it around
>   the Y axis of the stage, i.e.
>   horizontal flipping. rotationZ: spin,
>   baby spin o’er the Z axis of the
>   stage. As far as I’m concerned, a spin
>   around the Z axis is the same as
>   rotation (unless, for some reason, the
>   Z axis does not cross through the
>   orientation point of the object).
>   [http://actionscription.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/3d-rotation/]

Comment: Oh, you just want to rotate on X-axis only or Y-axis only?  
Sorry, i read it too quickly

Comment: Yes, rotationX is what I would like to do, but as I am using Flash CS3 I have to find something else that does the same.