# MovieClip in perspective

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, away3d

I would like to have a MovieClip that has a bit of depth.
I can't use rotationX, rotationY or rotationZ because I have to use Flash CS3.

The first image is what I have now, a flat movieclip. The second is what I should have.

[image]
[image]

I already tried using a matrix, but that didn't work.
I posed [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184199/as3-simulating-rotationx-with-matrix) about it, and there somebody sugested that I should use a 3D engine to get the result I want.

Since it was a MovieClip that had to be in 3D I used now a MovieClipSprite.

```
var movieClipSprite:MovieClipSprite = new MovieClipSprite(myMC);
var view:View3D = new View3D({x:200,y:200});
        
var cam:Camera3D = new Camera3D();
cam.zoom = 1;
cam.y = 100;            
view.camera = cam;
cam.lookAt(new Number3D(0, 0, 0));
    
this.addChild(view);
view.scene.addSprite(movieClipSprite);
view.render();
```

It didn't matter how I changed the camera, I always have got the same result. The flat movieclip.

Then I read in the Away3D documentation

> MovieClipSprite: Spherical billboard
> (always facing the camera) sprite
> object that uses a movieclip as it's
> texture. Draws individual display
> objects inline with z-sorted triangles
> in a scene.

I think that's why it always gives the same result.

I also tried something with MovieMaterial, but I never have got that working.

Can you please help me to put my movieclip in perspective?

Thanks a lot!

Vincent

Comment: Vinzcent if you are posting a new question on how to move forward with your project using away3d, then please select the appropriate "correct" answer in your previous question. By not doing that, this appears more like a double post than a question regarding a new issue.

Comment: continuing from my first comment for others who might be curious, this question is *nearly* a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184199/as3-simulating-rotationx-with-matrix. I say this because these issues could technically be addressed in the first question. If not then I think it's only best to close out the above question and edit this question to clearly define this as a new issue.

Comment: Cool okay I'm heading to bed cause its almost 5 am where I am but I'll check this question in the morning and if no one has answered it I'll post an example in code of how to do this with away3DLite (assuming that's what you're looking for).

Comment: Thanks, I'd very much appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "view.render" in a enter_frame function ?

It worked for me with flashdevelop & Away3d 4.0 :

```
    public var aSprite:Plane = new Plane(new ColorMaterial(0xFF0000));
    public var cam:Camera3D = new Camera3D();
    public var view:View3D = new View3D(null,cam);

    public function test() 
    {
        this.addChild(view);

        var vec:Vector3D = new Vector3D();
        cam.y = -300;
        cam.lookAt(vec);

        view.scene.addChild(aSprite);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
    }

    public function onFrame(e:Event):void
    {
        view.render();
    }
```